# Is there a way in Grease Pencil to cut the end of those stripes?

Tags: shortcut, grease-pencil

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way in Grease Pencil to cut the end of those stripes?

Comment: I'm not a specialist in this area, but Grease Pencil Layers can be set up very flexibly  to mask one another: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/grease_pencil/properties/masks.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lI0V-0UuhmE&t=280s  ..

Answer (score 0):

You could go into *Edit Mode*, select the brushstrokes you wish to erase, and hit *Delete*. Or you could use the Erase tool or the Cutter tool.

In Grease Pencil, there's a toolbar on your left. Select the *Scissors* icon.
[image]

Next, highlight the line you want to remove and release your mouse.

[image]

The line should then be removed.
[image]